# Service Cardinality in spaces?

Tags: ibm-cloud

What's the limit on the number of services and limits of any specific service within a Bluemix Standard account?

It appears like we can create multiple instances of some services, but curious what the limits are to that.

Answer (score 0):

The **Bluemix Lite account** is new and the limitations of that account are documented here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/account/index.html#liteaccount

With a Lite account, you can use any service in the Bluemix catalog that has a Lite plan. However, you can only provision 1 instance per Lite plan. There are a limited # of services that have Lite plans today. As of the date of this response, you are limited to the following services:

- IBM® Bluemix® Availability Monitoring
- IBM® Push Notifications for Bluemix®
- IBM® Cloudant® NoSQL DB for Bluemix®
- IBM Watson™ Conversation
- IBM Watson™ IoT Platform
- IBM Watson™ Language Translator
- IBM Watson™ Personality Insights
- IBM Watson™ Tone Analyzer

As stated in the URL above, the service list is subject to change as well as its Bluemix region availability.